Postgis geography column with pg-mem gives error
I have this column in my typeORM entity :
  @Index({ spatial: true })
  @Column({
    type: 'geography',
    spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
    srid: 4326,
  })
  geolocation!: Point;

I'm using pg-mem for my tests
But on init it crashes with this error
    1  CREATE TABLE "user" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),  "geolocation" geography(Point,4326), ...(other columns)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Unexpected word token: "point". Instead, I was expecting to see one of the following:

        - A "int" token

So basically you can register equivalent type but I could not make it work so far.
I'm not sure if you are supposed to register the type in postgis or directly in public so i tried both.
So fat none of these have worked.
db.registerExtension('postgis', schema => {
  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'geography',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });

  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'geography(Point,4326)',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });

  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'point',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });

  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'Point',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });

  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'Point,4326',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });

  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: '(Point, 4326)',
    equivalentTo: DataType.point,
    isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
  });
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: 'geography',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: () => true,
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: 'geography(Point,4326)',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: () => true,
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: 'point',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: 'Point',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: 'Point,4326',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
});

db.public.registerEquivalentType({
  name: '(Point, 4326)',
  equivalentTo: DataType.point,
  isValid: geo => geo !== null && geo !== undefined,
});



Could anyone make this work ? It basically ruins all my test

To properly register the geography type with pg-mem, you need to handle geography(pOint, 4326) type correctly. This involves creating a custom type that can be recognized by pg-mem. Take a look at the code below and see if it helps, you can also adjust as you feel like:


import { newDb, DataType } from 'pg-mem';
import { Point } from 'geojson';

const db = newDb();

db.registerExtension('postgis', schema => {
  // Register geography type with point and SRID 4326
  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'geography(Point,4326)',
    equivalentTo: DataType.jsonb,
    isValid: (geo: any) => typeof geo === 'object' && geo.type === 'Point',
  });

  // Register Point type explicitly
  schema.registerEquivalentType({
    name: 'point',
    equivalentTo: DataType.jsonb,
    isValid: (geo: any) => typeof geo === 'object' && geo.type === 'Point',
  });
});

// Define the table with the geography column
db.public.none(`
  CREATE TABLE "user" (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "geolocation" geography(Point,4326),
    ...(other columns)
  )
`);

// Get the table reference
const userTable = db.public.getTable('user');

// Insert a sample user with geographical data
userTable.insert({
  id: 'some-uuid',
  geolocation: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [12.34, 56.78],
  } as Point,
});



I hope this helps.
